# LUIS - is it possible to "merge" two datetimeV2 entities

Tags: nlp, azure-language-understanding

We have English LUIS model that has active entities of type `datetimeV2`

It works fine but in sentennce

> today 26th march

there are two entities detected while only one is desired - see below.

Is it possible to detect this sample sentence as one entity? E.g. using Composite entity?

---

```
"entities": [
{
    "entity": "today",
    "type": "builtin.datetimeV2.date",
    "resolution": ...
},
{
    "entity": "26th april",
    "type": "builtin.datetimeV2.date",
    "resolution": ...
    }   
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately we cannot remove the labels of [prebuilt entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/pre-builtentities). The behavior of prebuilt entities is **pre-trained and cannot be modified.** And we cannot wrap same entity type (datetimeV2 twice as child) under composite entity as child entities. A [composite entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-entity-types#composite-vs-hierarchical-entities) is made up of other entities, such as prebuilt entities, list entities, and simple. The separate entities form a whole entity.